# Looking for a Rosé recommendation

Tags: wine, recommendations

I would like to add a few bottles of Rosé to my wine collection and would like a few recommendations on good  Rosé.  If you have one, let me know what it is.

Comment: What kind of rosé do you usually like? Might be good information to add if you're looking for recommendations that you'll enjoy!

Comment: Pretty much anything from Provence.

Answer (score 4):

**Looking for a Rosé recommendation?**

The ultimate recommendation would involve that particular variety of Rosé you may be interested in.

Having lived many years in France and having drank wine on a very regular bases while overseas, I would like to recommend the Tavel Rosé.

There is just something awesome about wine made from grapes in the Rhone Valley!

> [**Tavel Rosé**](https://tastessence.com/types-of-rose-wine)
>
> The French wine region of Tavel, on the sloping bank of Rhone, is known for its famous rosé wines. In fact, Tavel wines are only available in rosé variety. The rosé wines of this region are also known as the **“The King of Rosés”**. From light salmon to ruby pink, there are a variety of rosé wines with complex aromas of summer fruits and a full, rounded mouth with hints of spice. The wines in this region are made from Grenache, Syrah, and Clairette varieties.
>
> **Food Pairing**
>
> It can be served as an aperitif or with seafood pasta, cold fish starters, herb sausages, and a variety of cheese.

The following may be of some interest in making an ultimate choice of Rosé that one may be looking for as a recommendation:

- [A Guide to 10 Different Styles of Rosé](https://winefolly.com/tips/guide-styles-of-rose-wine/)
- [Rosé (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ros%C3%A9)
- [A Comprehensive Guide to Rosé Wine | The 10 Perfect Styles](https://www.wtso.com/blog/a-comprehensive-guide-to-rose-wine-the-10-perfect-styles/?_vsrefdom=googleads&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImcm84f-d6gIVWiCtBh3XLw9EEAAYAyAAEgKhevD_BwE)
- [10 Shades Of Rosé](https://vinepair.com/wine-blog/10-shades-of-rose-wine/)

[image: 10 Shades Of Rosé]

Answer (score 3):

Ken Graham's answer is excellent. I will say that when I visited Provence, I found just about every rose delicious. In general, everyday Cote de Provence rose is less expensive than Tavel rose. So I might suggest starting with a Cote de Provence rose and graduate to a Tavel.

Comment: Excellent answer!